# CPU scheduling Decisions

Tags: operating-systems, scheduling, cpu, process-scheduling

[Operating System - CPU scheduling Decisions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53037/operating-system-cpu-scheduling-decisions?newreg=08ec7d77438041519f03ff440afd01bb)

The question above talks about why CPU scheduling does not take place when ready to running.

But I wonder **why CPU scheduling does not take place when new to ready**. I think it is similar to the process of waiting to ready. They both add processes to ready without changing processes that are running.

[image]

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpu-scheduling-in-operating-systems/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a new process in the ready queue, you are just adding the process, not changing anything to running as a result. With a non-preemptive scheduler this is also the case for waiting to ready. But, when you have a preemptive scheduler, tasks that come from waiting to ready get a higher priority than newly running tasks, so that "scheduler decision-making" is determining the priority of this newly ready task in the queue. It looks like they get a higher priority than new tasks because they've already been delayed enough waiting for IO.